# Composite pattern traversal adding leaf and components to parents

Tags: java, design-patterns, file-io, tree, composite

So i have a file which I am reading in, its in the format
components can have arbitrary  number of child both components and leafs.

```
comp1 : data
comp1 childs : comp2, comp3, comp4
comp2 : Data
comp2 childs : leaf 1, comp5
leaf 1 :data
comp5 : data
comp5 childs: leaf2:
Leaf2 : data
comp3 :data
comp4 :data
```

what is the best easiest way to add childs to parent nodes? My brain is fried and cannot reason this. please help, Im using a composite pattern, comp(osite) implements  component, and leaf implements component. my comp class has an Arraylist to hold its children.

Edit:
Well Its prob not the super correct way but I got it to work as need by doing this. Where I read my file in I store all my components in a large temp file . and whenever it read in the child nodes i stored them as strings in as lists in a list with the first index being the parent nodes id name. 
this is after I fileread everthing.

```
for(ArrayList ls:listOf){
    if (ls.size()>1){
        for (int i = 1; i<ls.size();i++){
            for(Component comp:tempchilds){
                if(ls.get(i).equals(comp.name())){
                    rootComp.add(ls.get(0).toString(), comp);
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

this is what my component does to find the parent in root and add child to it

```
public void add(String s,Component component){
    if(this.name.equals(s)){
        comps.add(component);
    }else{
        if(!comps.isEmpty()){
            for(Component comp:comps){
                comp.add(s, component);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

pretty bad, but it works haha. still learning, feel free to tell me how bad it is and why.

Comment: Recursion is your friend.

Comment: I cant, well couldnt figure out how to do it recursively.  so the way i just got it to work is probably pretty sloppy. I just made it an operation in my component class. I then made when reading inthe file a list of list of string which are the parent node, so comp1 would have a list [comp1, then any child nodes it should have at 1 to n.] I then made a loop to for each list in the the list to check a large list of components and add it to the parent. using an operation in component comp class.